# How to add a new field to an array by id when fetching inside map

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I have a table in UI, this list comes in a GET request. I'm trying to add a new value to each row through another GET request, but I can't make a request inside a map...

```
 export const ProductsList: FC<{}> = () => {
    const [shoppingList, setShoppingList] = useState<any>([])
    const [loadComplete, setLoadComplete] = useState<boolean>(false)

    const getProductList = async () => {
      setLoadComplete(false)
      const response = await getShopList()
      return response.data._embedded
    }

    const getValues = async (id: string) => {
      const response = await getProductValues(id)
      return response.data._embedded.values
    }

    useEffect(() => {
      getProductList()
        .then((data) => {
          const response = data.products
          setShoppingList(response)
          setLoadComplete(true)
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          setLoadComplete(false)
          console.log(err)
        })
    }, [])

    useEffect(() => {
      const fetchData = (data) => {
        setShoppingList(
          data.map(async (element) => ({
            ...element,
            total_items: await getValues(element.id)[0].total_items, //this does not work
          })),
        )
      }
      fetchData(shoppingList)
    }, [loadComplete])

    return shoppingList.map((product) => {
      return (
        <Row key={product.id}>
          <Cell width={40}>
            <h1>{product.product_name}</h1>
          </Cell>

          <Cell width={30}>
            <Text weight='medium'>
              There is a total of ${product.total_items} items
            </Text>
          </Cell>
        </Row>
      )
   })
 }
```

For each row I want to search by its ID and show through another request it's value. I can't have those values in the same request, I have to do this way, but I can't find a solution that works.

Answer (score 1):

To answer you question specifically: in an `async` function, you can only use `await` in the function body, not in an implicit return.

```js
data.map(async element => {
  return {
  ...element,
  total_items: await getValues(element.id).then(x => x[0].total_items)
  }
})
```

Now, I doubt `setShoppingList` would be happy with an array of promises, so I advise to convert your array of promises to a promises of results:

```js
const fetchData = data => Promise.all(data.map(async element => {
  return {
  ...element,
  total_items: await getValues(element.id).then(x => x[0].total_items)
  }
})).then(setShoppingList)
```

Another approach is to take advantage of the fact that an object is a traversable, like arrays, and do the same operation we did with `Promise.all`, but with your objects. I called `syncronizeObject` an equivalent of `Promise.all` for objects.

```js
const fetchData = data => Promise.all(data.map(element => syncronizeObject({
   ...element,
   total_items: getValues(element.id).then(x => x[0].total_items)
}))).then(setShoppingList)

const syncronizeObject = obj => Promise.all(Object.values(obj))
    .then(vals => Object.keys(obj).map((key, i) => [key, vals[i]])).then(Object.fromEntries)
```

I let you deal with errors yourself but you may be interested in `Promise.allSettled`